# How do I send an email, according to the value of the custom meta key in WooCommerce orders?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have been trying to perform the action of sending an email according to the status of a meta_key that is in time format.

I can only do it according to the status of the order, but the most important thing is the date.

I share the code that I have made, but I think it needs a twist.

Something strange I have found is that now the post type is called shop_order_placehold and not shop_order, in `wp_post`

```
function add_order_expiration_date_field($order) {
    $expiration_date = get_post_meta($order->get_id(), '_order_expiration_date', true);
    ?>
    <div class="">
        <h4><?php _e('Expiration date', 'woocommerce'); ?></h4>
        <p class="form-field form-field-wide">
            <label for="order_expiration_date"><?php _e('Expiration date', 'woocommerce'); ?></label>
            <input type="datetime-local" class="input-text" name="order_expiration_date" id="order_expiration_date" value="<?php echo esc_attr($expiration_date); ?>" />
        </p>
    </div>
    <?php
}
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_order_details', 'add_order_expiration_date_field');


//Save due date when updating order
function save_order_expiration_date($order_id) {
    $expiration_date = isset($_POST['order_expiration_date']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['order_expiration_date']) : '';
    update_post_meta($order_id, '_order_expiration_date', $expiration_date);
}
add_action('woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta', 'save_order_expiration_date');

// Function to handle custom query parameter'_order_expiration_date'
function handle_custom_order_expiration_date_query( $query, $query_vars ) {
    if ( ! empty( $query_vars['_order_expiration_date'] ) ) {
        $query['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key' => '_order_expiration_date',
            'value' => esc_attr( $query_vars['_order_expiration_date']) ,
            'compare' => '=',
        );
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_data_store_cpt_get_orders_query', 'handle_custom_order_expiration_date_query', 10, 2 );

// Test function to send an email
function test_cron_mail() {
   // Define the custom query parameter '_order_expiration_date'
    $current_date_time = current_time( 'mysql' );
    $args = array(
        'status' => 'wc-completed',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => '_order_expiration_date',
                'value' => $current_date_time,
                'compare' => '<',
                'type' => 'DATETIME',
            ),  
        ),
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );

    // Apply filter to handle custom query parameter
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_data_store_cpt_get_orders_query', 'handle_custom_order_expiration_date_query', 10, 2 );

    // Perform order query
    $query = new WC_Order_Query( $args );
    echo 'args:  ';var_dump ($args) ;
    $orders = $query->get_orders(array();

    echo 'orders:  ';
    var_dump ($orders) ;

    // Delete the filter after performing the query
    remove_filter( 'woocommerce_order_data_store_cpt_get_orders_query', 'handle_custom_order_expiration_date_query', 10, 2 );

    // Scroll through expired orders and take necessary actions
    foreach ( $orders as $order ) {
        $order_id = $order->get_id();
        $billing_name = $order->get_billing_first_name();
        $billing_email = $order->get_billing_email();

        $subject = 'Hosting expired for ' . $billing_name;
        $message = 'Your hosting is expired. Please, contact us for further information.';

        // Make sure the email address isválida antes de enviar el correo
        if ( is_email( $billing_email ) ) {
            wp_mail( $billing_email, $subject, $message );
        }
    }
}

// Add cron task for test function
add_action( 'init', 'schedule_test_cron_job' );

function schedule_test_cron_job() {
    // Set a 5 minute delay for the test cron task to run
    $timestamp = time() + 1 * 60;

    // Schedule the test cron task
    wp_schedule_single_event($timestamp, 'test_cron_job');
}

add_action('test_cron_job', 'test_cron_mail');
```

I hope you can help me figure out where the error is.

Comment: sorry , i edited

Comment: Are you using (or have you enabled) [WooCommerce High-Performance Order Storage](https://woo.com/document/high-performance-order-storage/): The related option settings are located in admin WooCommerce > Settings > Advanced > Features > Order data storage…

Comment: yes, it was activated

Comment: I had orders to synchronize, I synchronized them, and I activated compatibility mode. now in wp_post I see the post_type shop_order.